# Converting string to digits in Python

Tags: python

I have a string:

```
x = "12.000"
```

And I want it to convert it to digits. However, I have used int, float, and others but I only get `12.0` and i want to keep all the zeroes. Please help!

I want `x = 12.000` as a result.

Comment: Trailing zeros after the decimal point have absolutely no effect on the number represented. Just store it using any appropriate number type, and if you have a requirements to show exactly N digits to the user, simply pad the string with zeros.

Comment: @delnan: But they *can* have an effect on calculations using the number, especially in [scientific situations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Significant_figures).

Answer (score 6):

[`decimal.Decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) allows you to use a specific precision.

```
>>> decimal.Decimal('12.000')
Decimal('12.000')
```

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to perform **calculations that take precision into account**, the easiest way is to probably to use the [uncertainties](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) module.  Here is an example

```
>>> import uncertainties
>>> x = uncertainties.ufloat('12.000')
>>> x
12.0+/-0.001
>>> print 2*x
24.0+/-0.002
```

The [uncertainties](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) module transparently handles uncertainties (precision) for you, whatever the complexity of the mathematical expressions involved.

---

The [decimal](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html) module, on the other hand, does not handle uncertainties, but instead sets the number of digits after the decimal point: **you can't trust all the digits given by the decimal module**.  Thus,

```
>>> 100*decimal.Decimal('12.1')
Decimal('1210.0')
```

whereas 100*(12.1±0.1) = 1210±10 (not 1210.0±0.1):

```
>>> 100*uncertainties.ufloat('12.1')
1210.0+/-10.0
```

Thus, the decimal module gives '1210.0' even though the precision on 100*(12.1±0.1) is 100 times larger than 0.1.

---

So, if you want numbers that have a fixed number of digits after the decimal point (like for accounting applications), the decimal module is good; if you instead need to perform calculations with uncertainties, then the [uncertainties](http://packages.python.org/uncertainties/) module is appropriate.

(Disclaimer: I'm the author of the uncertainties module.)

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested by [the decimal python lib](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html).

You can set the precision with `getcontext().prec`.